# Where do I find the standard licensing agreement on a video that's on YouTube?

Tags: video, post-production

Where do I find the licensing agreement on a video so I know if I can use it or not?

Answer (score 2):

From YouTube's [help pages](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2797468?hl=en-GB&ref_topic=2778546):

> The standard YouTube licence remains the default setting for all uploads.

And Fair Use typically does not apply on the standard licence. See [here](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6396261?hl=en-GB&ref_topic=2778546) for specifics, and when it does apply. The other option is Creative Commons:

> Creative Commons licences provide a standard way for content creators to grant someone else permission to use their work. YouTube allows users to mark their videos with a Creative Commons CC BY licence.

Videos licenced under CC by Attribution 3.0 have this in the info under the video (you may need to click on Show More)

> Licensed under Creative Commons: By Attribution 3.0 License
>
> http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.

Answer (score 0):

Most videos aren't free to use.
The ones specifically made for free use often have a CC or Free Use in the title or in the description.

CC standing for creative commons.

If not, you may need to contact the creator